# How to conditionally compile for tvOS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

How do I conditionally compile code for iOS and tvOS in the same file in the Swift language?
I have tried all the Objective-C style `#if` etc. for `TARGET_OS_TV` as mentioned in the Apple docs, and some other answers. But I have not found a working solution for Swift code.

Comment: this should work #if TARGET_OS_TV
    NSLog(@"tVOS");
#else
    NSLog(@"Not iOS");
#endif

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
#if os(OSX)
// compiles for OS X
#elseif os(iOS)
// compiles for iOS
#elseif os(tvOS)
// compiles for TV OS
#elseif os(watchOS)
// compiles for Apple watch
#endif
```

Comment: what is the os for CarPlay

Answer (score 9):

This is also covered by Apple under the heading [Targeting Apple TV in Your Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH12-SW15)

> Listing 1-1 Conditionalizing code for tvOS in Objective-C

```
 #if TARGET_OS_TV
     NSLog(@"Code compiled only when building for tvOS.");
 #endif
```

> Listing 1-2 Conditionalizing code for tvOS in Swift

```
#if os(tvOS)
NSLog(@"Code compiled only when building for tvOS.");
#endif

if #available(tvOS 9.1,*) {
    print("Code that executes only on tvOS 9.1 or later.")
}
```

Comment: Extremely helpful to see the difference between Objective-C and Swift syntax.

Comment: Of course Apple accidentally put Objective-C code (NSLog()) in its Listing 1-2 conditional Swift code, so it should actually be this:

#if os(tvOS)
    print("Code compiled only when building for tvOS.")
#endif

if #available(tvOS 9.1,*) {
    print("Code that executes only on tvOS 9.1 or later.")
}

Answer (score 6):

```
#if <build configuration> && !<build configuration>
statements
#elseif <build configuration>
statements
#else
statements
#endif
```

Where build configuration can be :-

    os(abc) where valid values for abc are OSX, iOS, watchOS, tvOS, Linux

    arch(abc) where valid values for abc are x86_64, arm, arm64, i386

See Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13):

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a documentation reference -- though I'd like one -- but I've seen Apple sample code with sections like:

```
    #if os(iOS) || os(tvOS)
    #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

just for other people arrive there for visionOS:

```
#elseif os(visionOS)


#endif
```